# Leave git bash open after running script

Tags: git-bash

I have a .sh script with the following code

```
cd C:/Users/... && git add . && git commit -m "QC" && git push && read
```

and the read command at the end does not keep the window open afterwards. Adding the read command worked for the following:

```
cd C:/Users/... && git pull && read
```

It runs and leaves the window open for me to read after pulling. Can anyone help me with the former script so it stays open after the commit so I can read it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are combining all your commands with `&&`, so if any of your commands fail, the following commands (including `read`) will simply not be executed.

For example : if there is no change in your repo, `git commit` (as in your `git commit -m "QC"` command) will exit with code 1.

---

Just run `read` unconditinally :

```
cd .. && git add . && ... && git push
read

# if you really want to see your script on one line: '...; read'
```